# Switching between SD cards connected in parallel

Tags: parallel, storage

I got an old device that uses an SD card that's not easily accessible since it's all in an enclosed box. It only has one slot.

What I was intending to do was create a custom PCB and parallel the SD board (so now there's 2 or 3). All the SD card tracks would be in parallel on the board (DAT0/1/2 etc.) apart from the VDD lines.

I would be using a switch to go in-between the VDD lines to go in-between the different SD cards and it would function as normal is my intention.

Is this the suggested way? Total beginner here.

Comment: Could an SD card extender cable solve your problem?

Comment: The fact that these are SD cards is a key part of the problem - why are you trying to obscure it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That probably won't work. Not only would both card and reader drive an unpowered device and stub lines, which poses a significant signal integrity problem. but chances are you'd risk back-powering the "off" SD card through the data lines.

You could, instead, use a *bus switch* IC to switch between the two two cards.

Make sure the bandwidth of the switch IC is high enough – rule of thumb for digital communications is that it needs to be 7 to 9 times the bit rate on the bus. We don't know which SD card standard you're using, so this is something you'll have to figure out.

Comment: if SPI mode is what you're using, a simple switch would do. But a switch IC that switches the data lines as well reduces the load on the bus, and would disconnect any potentially misbehaving SD Card. I wouldn't count on SD cards actually putting outputs into high-impedance mode  – it's practically never needed (outside of this scenario here).

Comment: use a switch IC. these things cost cents to single-digit euros. They're really easy to use – there's an input that you can either pull high or low (e.g. using a mechanical switch!) and that switch over the lines. That's it. I don't see how anything else would be easier.

Answer (score 16):

Switching VDD lines is not a good idea because applying non-zero voltages/signals to an unpowered chip may damage the chip (see Absolute Maximum Ratings).

SD cards can operate in SPI mode or SD mode.

- In SPI mode, CS pin (Card Select) can be used to tell which card will get the commands. **SPI mode allows full parallel operation** so you can switch between cards by using CS pin. **IMPORTANT:** SD interface controllers pull the MISO line high after the host pulls the CS line high following a command sent. This is an indication of being busy, or in other words, processing command. They release (i.e. Hi-Z) the MISO line once they processed the command. Some SD card interface controllers are not fast enough (or maybe there is another reason) thus can't release the MISO line quickly. Care must be taken.
- In SD mode, DAT# and CMD lines should be separated. But CLK can be common.

You should know which mode the card and the host operate in.

Comment: I agree not a good idea. Some SD cards did have a problem with not setting the MISO pin to high impedance mode when deselected with CS, so it depends on the cards.

Comment: @Justme you are absolutely right that some SD cards don't release the MISO line. I should have added that. Good spot.

Comment: @Jery this is not the point. You need the card to be powered on to be able to properly deal with the CS line, else your card might be damaged, or do arbitrary things with the data lines. Even if it's powered on, you get no good guarantees that the data outputs of the card behave nicely, is what Justme is saying.